# Jaxb Xew Plugin in Maven JAX WS

Tags: jaxb2, jaxws-maven-plugin, jaxb-xew-plugin

```
mvn generate-sources
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder          org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBu
ilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building epay_api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (wsimport-generate-sources) @ api ---
[INFO] Processing: file:/C:/service.wsdl
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1256), build is platform dependent!
[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, C:\api\src\main\java, -d, C:\api\target\classes,     -verbose, -Xnocompile, -B-debug, -B-no-header, -B-Xxew, -B-Xx
ew:instantiate lazy, -B-Xxew:delete, -B-extension, -B-b C:\api/src/main/res
ources/jaxb_binding.xml, "file:/C:/api/src/main/resources/service.w
sdl"]
[DEBUG] JAXB Compilation started (XmlElementWrapperPlugin.onActivated):
[DEBUG]   buildId         : 2.2.7
[DEBUG]   targetDir       : .
[DEBUG]   defaultPackage  : null
[DEBUG]   defaultPackage2 : null
[DEBUG]   debug           : true
[DEBUG]   verbose         : true
[DEBUG]   quiet           : false
[DEBUG]   grammars        : 0
[DEBUG] Argument[0] = -Xxew
[DEBUG] Argument[0] = -Xxew:instantiate
[DEBUG] Argument[0] = -Xxew:delete
parsing WSDL...


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError     cannot be cast
to java.lang.Exception
        at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:87)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.593 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-04T04:06:54+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport     (wsimport-ge
nerate-sources) on project epay_api: Mojo failed - check output -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the     following arti
cles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my simple pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>api</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsimport-generate-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlLocation>src/main/resources/*</wsdlLocation>
                        <xjcArgs>
                            <xjcArg>-debug</xjcArg>
                            <xjcArg>-no-header</xjcArg>

                            <xjcArg>-Xxew</xjcArg>
                            <xjcArg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</xjcArg>
                            <xjcArg>-Xxew:delete</xjcArg>

                            <xjcArg>-extension</xjcArg>
                            <xjcArg>-b ${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb_binding.xml</xjcArg>
                            <xjcArg>-XJsr303Annotations</xjcArg>
                            <!-- <xjcArg>-Xfluent-api</xjcArg> -->
                            <!-- <xjcArg>-Xvalue-constructor</xjcArg> -->
                        </xjcArgs>

                    </configuration>


                </execution>

            </executions>
            <dependencies> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

And -e -X switch does not reveal anything about this error

"main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast
on
.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:87)

This is the most basic configuration i am trying.

C:\api>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

C:\api>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T21:37:52+04:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin..
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1256
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

What is wrong with my configuration? Appreciate any help thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem. Using Ant instead of the Maven plugin, but the essence remains te same. I had to add commons-logging-api-1.1.jar to the classpath in order to make it work. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [samples of the jaxb xew plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/tree/master/samples) you need to use a newer version of the [jaxws maven plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/). The sample uses version 2.3.1-b03 which is also working in my project. Older versions of this plugin are probably compiled against a library that is incompatible with the [jaxb xew plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin).

If you browse the sample code history you will find a configuration for the jaxws maven plugin version 2.2, too.

Comment: I agree that the easiest solution would be to use newer version of `jaxws-maven-plugin`. Older versions are compiled against "old" `jaxb-xjc`, but with some quirks I think it is possible to make v2.3 working.

Answer (score 8):

The workaround from https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS_COMMONS-129 helped me:

```
    <configuration>
         <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
         </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Worked for me !  but ... why ?

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth:  I had the same sort of error - using Maven 3.2.2 and I had the jaxws-maven-plugin set to 2.3.  This stopped working with the problem:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError     cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception

Reading the threads and the Stack Overflow posts, it seemed that going to a new version of the plugin would help.  Moved to 2.3.1-b01 all the way to 2.3.1-b03.  This changed the issue to now results in:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/*
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.*

Seems that there is a well documented issue with the 2.3.1-b03 working with any Maven release that is >=3.1.  You can find more info by searching (there are JIRAs and bug reports open on it) or start [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound).

Ultimately I moved back down to 2.2. for the plugin and this worked without and issue.

Comment: moving from 2.3 back to 2.2 fixed it for me too

Comment: @BoneSmuggler - I am using org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons's jaxws-maven-plugin. have you got any workaround for org.sonatype.aether error in 2.3.1-b03 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with add this plugin in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Needed with JAXP 1.5 -->
        <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
        </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on
>   project birst-soap-client: Mojo failed - check output.

But the cause is something in Jenkins. The Jenkins job name has some spaces in it ("file:/data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core%20-%20Release%20Tag+Nexus/...), and that caused a failure to execute "jaxws:wsimport".
But stragely, Jenkins list this as [INFO] instead of [ERROR].
After removing the spaces in Jenkins job name. The build executed successfully.
The exerpt is listed below.

> [INFO] [INFO] Processing:
>   file:/data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core%20-%20Release%20Tag+Nexus/thirdparty/birst-soap-client/src/main/resources/wsdl/CommandWebService.5.19.wsdl
>   [INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8), build is platform
>   dependent! [INFO] [INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s,
>   /data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core - Release
>   Tag+Nexus/thirdparty/birst-soap-client/target/generated-sources/wsimport, -d, /data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core - Release Tag+Nexus/thirdparty/birst-soap-client/target/classes, -verbose,
>   -Xnocompile, -B-XautoNameResolution, -p, com.birst, -target, 2.0, "file:/data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core%20-%20Release%20Tag+Nexus/thirdparty/birst-soap-client/src/main/resources/wsdl/CommandWebService.5.19.wsdl"]
>   [INFO] directory not found: /data/jenkins/workspace/Dpm-Flyer-Core